# .diff is not a function on moments.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I try to do a little script using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), that shows me how many hours and minutes (seperate) I have until a specific hour.

```
var TimeA = moment('08:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss');
var TimeB = moment('16:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss');
var DiffAB = TimeA.diff(TimeB);
var DiffHours = DiffAB.format('H');
var DiffMinutes = DiffAB.format('mm');

console.log('TimeA: ' + TimeA);
console.log('TimeB: ' + TimeB);
console.log('Difference A-B: ' + DiffAB);
console.log('Diff Hours: ' + DiffHours);
console.log('Diff Minutes: ' + DiffMinutes);
```

Thats what I've tried so far. But I get the following error:

```
TimeA.diff is not a function
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `.format` returns a string and not `moment` object

Comment: When you fix the initial problem and now face a new problem, you should be asking a new question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `.format()`, what you get back is a String. You're no longer dealing with a moment object.

Comment: When answer helps you resolve the original issue, but now you've unearthed a new issue, you should accept the answer to the original issue and create an entirely new question for the new issue. Don't keep editing the question to address multiple issues in a rolling fashion.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I am sorry.