# .diff is not a function in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to get the difference between two dates, but I'm getting the response: `Uncaught TypeError: x.diff is not a function`
On other topics I've seen I have to create a moment object, but for as far as I know, I'm doing that. 
Code:

```
function datecheck(){
  var y = moment($("#input_pickup_date").val(),"L").format("L");
  var x = moment().format("L");
  console.log(x.diff(y, 'days'));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.diff is not a function on moments.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279604/diff-is-not-a-function-on-moments-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), `moment().format()` returns a String, so your `x` and `y` variables are both Strings. If you need to both do calculations on and display the values, separate them out into different variables:

```
function datecheck() {
    var dateSubmitted = moment($("#input_pickup_date").val(), "L"), //your old x variable
        now = moment(), //your old y variable
        dateSubmittedDisplay = dateSubmitted.format("L"), //a string representing the submitted date in the format you wanted.
        nowDisplay = now.format("L"); //a string representing now in the format you wanted.

    console.log(x.diff(y, 'days'));
}
```